# How to open calendar app with react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

i need to open google calendar using my react native app. i can open a website in browser using Linking. but i can't find a way to open google calendar.

This i what i tried. do i need to modify AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={[mainStyle.dashboardGridItem, mainStyle.gridTwo]}
  onPress={() => Linking.openURL('calendar://app')}
>
  <FastImage
    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    style={mainStyle.dashboardGridIcon}
    source={calendarIcon}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  Linking.openURL('calshow:');
} else if(Platform.OS === 'android') { 
  Linking.openURL('content://com.android.calendar/time/');
}
```

Comment: is there any way to open Google Calendar in iOS?