# open google calendar from react native app

Tags: react-native, google-calendar-api, deep-linking, url-scheme

In a react native app, I want to create new event in google calendar
currently i am opening link that is opened in browser using

```
Linking.openURL('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?add=someuser@gmail.com&location=location')
```

I want to open it in the google calendar app
how it can be done?

I found some uri schemes that should help but could not make it work (cap://, webcal://, comgooglecalendar:// calshow://)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272944/how-to-open-calendar-app-with-react-native